# How to fix an int to hex conversion that presents a consistent minor difference?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, serial-port, hex

I've been developing this tool to help with the remote configuration of a power supply that uses the Modbus-RTU protocol through RS232 serial connection. It has this basic command structure to set the voltage and current that I commented out in the code down below.

A function receives two int values, convert them to hex and builds a command with the correct CRC code and return it as a byte array.

Everything seems to work fine up to some values that when converted and set into the power supply present a consistent difference of 0.01 (double typed final value presented in the power supply). These values are presented in the referenceValuesFix array, also in the code, in the int format (double set value * 100).

So for instance if I get to set 2.55V and 1.00A to the power supply, which the voltage value corresponds to the value 255 in the referenceValuesFix array, the correct hex command (without the CRC code) should be "01 10 00 00 00 02 04 00 ff 00 64" but it ends up sending "01 10 00 00 00 02 04 00 fe 00 64" instead.

I think it is something related to the conversion of the int input to its correspondent byte value but I am failing to point it out.

```
        public static byte[] GenerateInputCode(int voltage, int current)
        {
            int[] referenceValuesFix = { 024, 029, 057, 058, 113, 114, 115, 116, 201, 203, 205, 207,
                226, 228, 230, 232, 251, 253, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265,
                266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 402, 406, 410, 414, 427, 431, 435, 439, 452, 456, 460,
                464, 477, 481, 485, 489, 502, 506, 510, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520,
                521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 768, 769, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777,
                778, 779, 780, 781, 782, 783, 803, 804, 812, 820, 828, 829, 837, 845, 853, 854, 862,
                870, 878, 879, 887, 895, 903, 904, 912, 920, 928, 929, 937, 945, 953, 954, 962, 970,
                978, 979, 987, 995, 1003, 1004, 1012, 1020, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028, 1029, 1030,
                1031, 1032, 1033, 1034, 1035, 1036, 1037, 1038, 1039, 1280, 1281, 1282, 1283, 1284,
                1285, 1286, 1287, 1288, 1289, 1290, 1291, 1292, 1293, 1294, 1295, 1536, 1537, 1538,
                1539, 1540, 1541, 1542, 1543, 1544, 1545, 1546, 1547, 1548, 1549, 1550, 1551, 1606,
                1608, 1615, 1624, 1631, 1633, 1640, 1649, 1656, 1658, 1665, 1674, 1681, 1683, 1690,
                1699, 1706, 1708, 1715, 1724, 1731, 1733, 1740, 1749, 1756, 1758, 1765, 1774, 1781,
                1783, 1790, 1792, 1793, 1794, 1795, 1796, 1797, 1798, 1799, 1800, 1801, 1802, 1803,
                1804, 1805, 1806, 1807, 1808, 1815, 1824, 1831, 1833, 1840, 1849, 1856, 1858, 1861,
                1865, 1874, 1881, 1883, 1890, 1899, 1906, 1908, 1915, 1924, 1931, 1933, 1940, 1949,
                1956, 1958, 1965, 1974, 1981, 1983, 1990, 1999, 2006, 2008, 2015, 2024, 2031, 2033,
                2040, 2048, 2049, 2050, 2051, 2052, 2053, 2054, 2055, 2056, 2057, 2058, 2059, 2060,
                2061, 2062, 2063 };

            //01 - slave address
            //10 - function code
            //00 00 - register starting address
            //00 02 - registers to write to
            //04 - bytes to write
            //XX XX -voltage
            //XX XX -current
            //XX XX -CRC code

            byte slaveAddress = 0x1;
            byte functionCode = 0x10;
            ushort startAddress = 0x0;
            ushort numberOfPoints = 0x2;
            byte bytesToWrite = 0x4;
            ushort voltageToSet = (ushort)voltage;
            ushort currentToSet = (ushort)current;

            List<byte> entryCode = new List<byte>();

            entryCode.Add(slaveAddress);
            entryCode.Add(functionCode);
            entryCode.Add((byte)(startAddress >> 8));
            entryCode.Add((byte)startAddress);
            entryCode.Add((byte)(numberOfPoints >> 8));
            entryCode.Add((byte)numberOfPoints);
            entryCode.Add(bytesToWrite);
            entryCode.Add((byte)(voltageToSet >> 8));
            entryCode.Add((byte)voltageToSet);
            entryCode.Add((byte)(currentToSet >> 8));
            entryCode.Add((byte)currentToSet);

            int entryCodeSize = entryCode.Count;

            byte[] frame = new byte[entryCodeSize + 2];

            for (int i = 0; i <= entryCodeSize - 1; i++)
            {
                frame[i] = entryCode[i];
            }

            byte[] checkSum = CRC16(frame);
            frame[entryCodeSize] = checkSum[0];
            frame[entryCodeSize + 1] = checkSum[1];

            return frame;
        }

        private static byte[] CRC16(byte[] data)
        {
            byte[] checkSum = new byte[2];
            ushort reg_crc = 0XFFFF;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                reg_crc ^= data[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if ((reg_crc & 0x01) == 1)
                    {
                        reg_crc = (ushort)((reg_crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reg_crc = (ushort)(reg_crc >> 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            checkSum[1] = (byte)((reg_crc >> 8) & 0xFF);
            checkSum[0] = (byte)((reg_crc & 0xFF));
            return checkSum;
        }
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. I [broke it down](https://dotnetfiddle.net/asP3w7) to just the part that puts together everything but the CRC and it produced the expected values.

Comment: As a side note, you can simplify creation of `frame` by doing `entryCode.Add(0);` twice after all the other values have been added, `byte[] frame = entryCode.ToArray();`, and then adjust the indexing that assigns the checksum values, to `entryCodeSize-2` and `entryCodeSize-1`.

Comment: @madreflection, sorry for my rookie mistake. You're right, there was nothing wrong with the code. It was some conversion of the inputs prior to the function. Thanks for your response.

Comment: That's okay. It happens.

Comment: I'm voting to close it as not reproducible.